# ContentSizeFitter component timing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using `ContentSizeFitter` component to make Text component fit the height of the text and then displaying some sprites under the text depending on text size. Its kind of quest UI displaying rewards under the quest description. When I tried to use normal function the re sizing component was little too late and sprites position was based on previous Text component size. I delayed the method by using Invoke and its working now but is there a way to do it without the delaying? When is this `ContentSizeFitter` component activating?